# add timestamp to this code

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How do I add a timestamp in the format hh:mm:ss in column B (instead of "null")

```
  const values = [[new Date(), null, text]];
  const firstBlankCell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  firstBlankCell
    .offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values)
    .setNumberFormat('dd.MM.yyyy');
```

I have tried having `new Date()` again instead of `null` but then I can't get it to have a different format from the first instance.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you have tried to do what is being asked and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `setNumberFormat` use `setNumberFormats`, i.e.

```
firstBlankCell
    .offset(0, 0, values.length, values[0].length)
    .setValues(values)
    .setNumberFormats([['dd.MM.yyyy','hh:mm:ss', '0']]);
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats